# Как вызвать debounce с функцией abcd внутри?

Tags: reactjs, lodash

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вызываю в onChange в input. Подскажите, как обернуть правильно сделать debounce, чтобы консоль лог срабатывал только когда человек перестал вводить данные

Answer (score 0):

Устанавливаете use-debounce:

```
npm i use-debounce
```

Оборачиваете по примеру:

```
import { useDebouncedCallback } from 'use-debounce';

function Input({ defaultValue }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultValue);
  // Debounce callback
  const [debouncedCallback] = useDebouncedCallback(
    // function
    (value) => {
      setValue(value);
    },
    // delay in ms
    1000
  );

  // you should use `e => debouncedCallback(e.target.value)` as react works with synthetic evens
  return (
    <div>
      <input defaultValue={defaultValue} onChange={(e) => debouncedCallback(e.target.value)} />
      <p>Debounced value: {value}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```